# バイナリからデータをフォーマットを推測する

Tags: tcp, binary

下記リンク先は、ある投資用のアプリケーションの通信内容のバイナリのdumpです。

ここから意味のあるデータ(日経平均の値など)をparseしたいのですがどうすればいいのでしょうか?
このアプリケーションではリアルタイムで価格などの変動する様子が表示されています。

おそらく、何かのフォーマット(msgpackやjsonbなど)にして送られていると思うのですが、何の形式なのか判別できません。

何の形式であるかわかればparseできるのですが・・・

fileコマンドも試してみましたがうまくいきませんでした。

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/81b083fce661838032de25ca774178c7

#### 追記:

このdumpは日経平均先物データの表示をしているときのデータです。
このアプリケーションではデータの種類は株価、先物、FX、海外の市場の指標などいろいろと取得することができます。
ただ、株価から先物などに表示を切り替える際に、そこそこ時間がかかっているのでもしかしたら現在表示されているものだけが来ているのかもしれません。

アプリから見える値ではありませんが、`0000004F`から`0000005F`にかけてasciiであらわすと
`20180307.210053`となっており、このデータが送られた時間のようです。

Comment: dumpが大きくなり貼り付けられなくなったのでgistに移動

Comment: そのアプリケーションはこのような解析を許しているのでしょうか。（SO的には違法スレスレであったとしてもプログラムの問題であれば扱って良いはずでオフトピではないです）

Comment: フォーマット不明なのにバイナリデータ表現の"区切り"が存在する理由はなぜでしょうか？通信パケット(UDP？)の境界？

Comment: 具体的にはどんな値が取得できることを期待しているのでしょうか。場合によってはAPIなどの公開情報を取得した方が簡単に済むかもしれません。

Comment: @cubick 情報を追記しました。

Answer (score 5):

推測するにはサンプルデータや手がかりとなる情報が少なすぎると思います。
"投資用"とは株価(国内のみor国外含め)？指数のみor個別銘柄？為替？仮想通貨？etc

- データを複数回(時間をおいて)取得して「変化がある箇所」「変化のない箇所」などからアタリを付ける。
- アプリから正規の手段で見える値がダンプに表れないか調べてみる。

Answer (score 1):

ほとんどの部分は0x11が区切りになっているテキストです。何らかの汎用フォーマットかもしれませんが、キーとなりそうな値が見えないので、パーサを通したところでどの部分が何の値かは結局自分で想像するしかありません。